# How to modify the typesetting of nomencl header?

Tags: macros, sectioning, nomenclature

The **nomencl** package typesets the header of the `nomenclature` list as a `\section*` in the `article` document class. How can I change it to `\subsection*`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could load the `etoolbox` package and issue the following command (after having loaded the `nomencl` package as well, naturally):

```
\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}{\section*}{\subsection*}{}{}
```

Comment: Great.... thank you very much indeed for the prompt answer.